# AJAX success callback JSON undefined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Here is the JSON returned from my php:

```
{
   "approvalSource":[
       {"role_name":"role_1","approval_req_id":"3"},                                                   
       {"role_name":"role_2","approval_req_id":"2"}
    ],
   "doc_source":[
       {"document_name":"testDoc","doc_req_id":"2"}
    ]
}
```

How come `alert(JSON.stringify(data.doc_source));` returns undefined?

Comment: I'm afraid your problem is somewhere else. That works perfect if the json is as you say. http://jsfiddle.net/y3a5R/

Comment: Its more likely the way you are requesting the json is incorrect, could you show the full code you are using?

Comment: Thanks everyone, my problem was that i forgot to explicitly define dataType: "json" in my ajax call....it was driving me crazy! If you care to take the time to post your responses as answers ill give cred to everyone for the replies

Comment: @A.O. also check below .. your way of accessing a key in incorrect. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @woofmeow yes you are correct thats why i gave you an upvote. However I needed the data in JSON format so you can access doc_source with the dot notation (as well as square brackets)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the `doc_source` incorrectly. This would be the right way to access the property.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data["doc_source"]));
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be useful to see the code that you are using to request and parse the JSON, but some thoughts:

I have often found that this problem is caused by the Content-Type header of HTTP request for the JSON. It needs to be something like 'application/json' for some libraries.

Another possibility is that you're using the string returned by the request that you're making rather than parsing it first.

Comment: I didn't notice that because I was busy replying. I was trying to help  though you know A.O. and given that you hadn't added the  dataType to your AJAX request your library would have been falling back to the Content-Type header (as I've said). So you're downgrading that response is a little harsh!

Comment: Also you did not provide an answer, merely "some thoughts". Woofmeow actually provided a working answer, as well as some of the people who commented on the original post Ill remove my downvote tho so you can build some rep lol. of course youll have to make an edit to your answer if you want it that bad

Comment: Yeah but woofmeow was wrong! You can access the value of the property your way. Also I could only provide 'some thoughts' in the absence of your code.  I don't want it that bad. I was just pointing out that you were being a bit destructive given that I was only trying to help.